# How can I create a full page workspace in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: macos, libreoffice

I prefer working with web view in LibreOffice writer. I'm working on a single web page with text in a single table. Very simple. Is there a way to make the table span the entire workspace, instead of being stuck over on the left side, as illustrated in this screenshot:
file:///Users/homesweet/Desktop/Cramps%20HTML%20TO%20HTML.html
If you scroll to the right of this web page, you will see just how much of the workspace is being underutilized.I want to work with a format that resembles the final format, a web page spanning the entire screen. Any suggestions? What am I missing?